# how to wrap a funtion inside a funtion in a single line to pass an arguments without executing it

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, tkinter

assume i have a simple funtion with 1 parameter

```
 def handle_click(text):
    print(text)
```

and i have many buttons and each of them has to pass different text to `handle_click` function

if i will pass an argument inside the button it will automatically all the funtion like:

```
Button(command=handle_click("display this"))
Button(command=handle_click("display that"))
Button(command=handle_click("show this"))
Button(command=handle_click("show that"))
```

but i want this function to be triggred when the button is clicked

In React.js i could use arrow funtion and do it like:

```
<Button onClick={() => {handleClick("show this")} }>
<Button onClick={() => {handleClick("show that")} }>
<Button onClick={() => {handleClick("so on")} }>
<Button onClick={() => {handleClick("so forth")} }>
```

Comment: i want to do the same in Python

Comment: Are you looking for `lambda` functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
Button(command=lambda: handle_click("display this"))
Button(command=lambda: handle_click("display that"))
Button(command=lambda: handle_click("show this"))
Button(command=lambda: handle_click("show that"))
```

It won't automatically run the function when you define these buttons, and whenever these buttons are clicked the `handle_click` function will run with the parameters you provided.

Comment: why did someone underestimated my question ? :(. Can u turn it back to 0

Comment: @SamandarYusupov: probably because questions like this has been asked and answered many times, and your question showed no signs of having done any research.

Comment: @SamandarYusupov next time, do your best at searching the web. There is very likely to be a question like this already.